# Why can't my Raspberry access the deeper commands?

Tags: pi-3

Can anyone tell me why my Pi can not access the deeper commands?

It always stops at the command `print("cho tao")`. I checked whether the conditional statement `if state2== True) :` worked. My `GPIO.input(19)` it also changes its value from 0 to 1. It should also work if my `state2` get the value of "1" but it does not.

[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: Please don't post code as images.  Cut & paste the text into your question.

Comment: @RalfFriedl - Please try to make your edits more complete, as there were a number of [other issues](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/98239/revisions) with the post.

Comment: do not use statements like `if (state2 == True):` ... that is same as `if (True == True):` ..... the statement should be `if (True):`, so use `if (state2):`

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that

`if (state2 = True)`

is a syntax error.

The line in the code appears to be

`if (state2 == True):`

which appears correct.

I think you may have an unprintable character on that line.

**I suggest you delete the line and type it in again.**